# How freely pack, arrange themselves according to width of each html elements (divs) inside large html element (div)?

Tags: css, styles, mdbootstrap

here's the image [image: link]

Like showing in this image I want to pack divs inside short eats div. For example, the fish bun div can put beside chinese rolls div likewise. I just want no white space there. Those divs are dynamically appear though.

I've added my laravel view code below if you need.

```
<div class="col-md-4 border border-primary rounded">
    <h4>Short Eats</h4>
    @foreach($shorteats as $shrt)                    
        <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="order('{{$shrt->dish_name}}')" class="btn btn-li btn-lg"> {{$shrt->dish_name}}</a>          
        </div>
    @endforeach                
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 border border-primary rounded">
    <h4>Rice</h4>
    @foreach($rice as $ric)                    
        <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="order('{{$ric->dish_name}}')" class="btn btn-li btn-lg"> {{$ric->dish_name}}</a>          
        </div>
    @endforeach                
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap` for CSS?

Comment: No mdbootstrap. No big difference btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class (e.g. `.menu-container`) to your `<div>`, that is the parent of your anchor tag, and use `flexbox` to (hopefully) achieve what you're after:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <a href="#" onclick="order('{{$ric->dish_name}}')" class="food-item btn btn-li btn-lg">{{$ric->dish_name}}</a>          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.food-item {
  // styles for your anchor tag go here
}
```

Comment: Great, @Gayath_chandi!